# Bootstrap date time widget overrides kendo telerik date time widget

Tags: .net, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, datepicker

I have a small problem with kendo grid. I have grid width editable date (not time only date ). I use Editor template to display kendo datepicker widgeton row edit. The problem is locally it works fine, but when I upload my web application to server, on edit, it displays bootstrap datepicker widget instead of kendo. I tried to set region and culture on my PC the same as in server but locally it still displays the correct (kendo) widget. Any ideas what might be wrong ?

My code: grid column:

```
c.Bound(b => b.ExpiryDate).Format((@System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name == "lt-LT") ? "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" : "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}").EditorTemplateName("DatePicker").Filterable(true).Width(150);
```

Field in view model:

```
[Display(Name = "ExpiryDate", ResourceType = typeof(Resource))]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime? ExpiryDate { get; set; }
```

Editor template:

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@model DateTime?

@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m).Value(Model))
```

HTML code generated for cell in edit mode (server version which displays bootstrap datepicker):

```
<td role="gridcell" data-container-for="ExpiryDate">
    <input class="text-box single-line" id="ExpiryDate" name="ExpiryDate" type="date" value="" data-bind="value:ExpiryDate">
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ExpiryDate" data-valmsg-replace="true">     </span>
</td>
```

HTML code generated locally (that correctly displays kendo widget):

```
<td role="gridcell" data-container-for="ExpiryDate">
    <span class="k-widget k-datepicker" style="">
        <span class="k-picker-wrap k-state-default">
            <input id="ExpiryDate" name="ExpiryDate" type="text" value="" data-role="datepicker" class="k-input" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="ExpiryDate_dateview" autocomplete="off" aria-disabled="false" data-bind="value:ExpiryDate" style="width: 100%;">
            <span unselectable="on" class="k-select" aria-label="select" role="button" aria-controls="ExpiryDate_dateview">
                <span class="k-icon k-i-calendar">
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <script>
        kendo.syncReady(function(){jQuery("#ExpiryDate").kendoDatePicker({"format":"d"});});
    </script> 
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ExpiryDate" data-valmsg-replace="true">
    </span>
</td>
```

Comment: Are the editor templates in the ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates folder deployed as well?  If the DatePicker.cshtml is not deployed the library will not be able to use it to generate the Editor.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, yes editor template in my project is located correctly: "\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\DatePicker.cshtml"

Answer (score 0):

I found soliution for this problem, for some reason .NET didin't liked name of editor template file. When I renamed "DatePicker.cshtml" to "DatePickerTemplate.cshtml" everything started to work just fine.